# How to fix - Unique extension association by intent is not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm attempting to associate a certain extension with my Android app, (using Android Studio). I need every .xyz file to allow the user to choose to open it with my app. For some reason, every solution I've encountered online simply does not work.

I've tried tens of different pathPatterns but with no avail. 
At times, no files are associated with the app, and at others all files are associated. Many times it seems that it totally ignores the specified pathPattern, and I seem to find no coloration between the 'regex' I supply and the behavior of the code.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.xyz"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz/>


        </intent-filter>
```

There are no extra '.'s in my path, I can honestly think of no other reason that this won't work! 
I would really appreciate any professional insight into this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

          <data android:scheme="file"  
             android:host="*" 
             android:pathPattern=".*\\.NSS" 
             android:mimeType="*/*"  />
        </intent-filter>
```